# How to save a number as contact?

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to save number entered in text box as a contact in android phone.
I have no idea how to do this.
Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: Did you even do any research efforts mate?

Comment: @Jaydeepsinh: Its always better to do some research before posting any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go here and find **Example: Inserting a Phone Number**
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 String enterednumber=textbox.getText().toString();
insertbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, fullname);
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,enterednumber);
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email);
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NOTES,
                        "Imported from moodle");
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, city
                        + " " + country);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
        });

//function


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (requestCode == 1) {

                }
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }
```